# How to setup nginx for reverse proxy with angular and dotnet core api for subdomains

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config

I have a frontend using angular and backend using dotnet core API.
The dotnet core API I usually check by visiting https://localhost:7285/swagger/index.html
I want to reverse proxy and display the frontend on admin.xyz.tech
and the configuration file of angular has servertemplateURL: adminservice.xyz.tech.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name xyz.tech;

    root /var/www/html;
    index index.html;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
}

server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name admin.xyz.tech;

    location / {
        alias /var/www/html/admin/dist/fuse;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }

    location /api {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:7295/;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection keep-alive;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }

    location /swagger {
        proxy_pass https://adminservice.xyz.tech/swagger;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection keep-alive;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
}
```

I have never worked with nginx and this is the code given by chatGPT 3.5
important:

Angular dist location: var/www/html/admin/dist/fuse

Dotnet bin location:
var/www/html/admin/publish